# Java - GetSelectedIndexes problem

Tags: java, jlist

My problem is my compiler isnt recognising getSelectedIndexes. I've got all the awt and swing libraries imported and PartyList is a Jlist thats been set up and works, can anyone give me any advice, thanks

else if(e.getSource() == jButton9) // if play button is pressed
    {

```
    int []selectedIndexes = PartyList.getSelectedIndexes();

    drawApp(4);
}
```

Comment: You really need to give more context than this. At least the declaration of getSelectedItems()

Answer (score 1):

You probably need PartyList partyList = new PartyList();

getSelectedIndexes is a instance level method.  You can't call it without instantiating the class...

Answer (score 0):

You want JList's [getSelectedIndices](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29), not getSelectedIndexes.